# What to study in summer free time as a 16 year old?

Tags: professional-education

I'm a 16 y old student who has recently finished 10th grade and has always been interested for tech. I knew some Windows tricks, and few more. Gaming and Netflix really occupied my time, but playing videogames started to bore me. A few months back, I bought a Raspberry Pi to install Plex and I enjoyed playing around with it, as the amount of control you had over the OS was enormous, a few weeks later, I downloaded and installed Ubuntu on my laptop, and learned some of the basic commands, what is systemd, and some basics of networking (thanks to the Pi) such as what is DHCP, a port, SSH, key-based authentication, types of DNS records (I liked to play around with dig, using +trace to see all the way the request goes), how a LAN works, hostnames... I became more and more interested and started researching stuff. But now that I finished school and I have summer break, I thought in learning something related, so that it may be useful for me in the future, where I seek to studying Computer Science, or some related degree.

I'm interested in Cybersecurity, as, among other things, it requires you to think out-of-the box. I played some basic CTF, from which I owe the little knowledge I have about Linux. I have researched about what you have to study, and it seems like to work in Cybersecurity you need to know about everything, from networking to C++, it's not an entry position for when you have your degree. So, actually, as I still don't have to go to the University in a few years, I haven't decided what path to follow, and I don't know what to try to learn this summer, if some Linux and bash scripting, to try to automate things, or to step up and do some Codeacademy course, as Python interests me, or what to do, as there's that much things that really overwhelms me, I feel there's so much to learn, from now to the years to come, and I'm open to your suggestions.

Comment: To know "cybersecurity" you need to know everything. The field is massive. Instead, choose a field *within* cybersecurity that interests you and start with that. We can't tell you what might  interest you. And expect to learn every day. I've been hacking computers since the mid-80's and I still learn every day and I don't feel like I know everything.